# ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape

Tags: python

I want to plot a plt.bar but my code won't do it?

My code is as follows. It's getting triggered at line:

```
plt.bar(t[1:], gr, label='Quarterly growth rate')
```

> shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape

[image]

Comment: Give us more details about `t` and `gr`. What are the types of these variables? Also, paste the code instead of showing the picture.